# Enable junit extensions autodetection with gradle

Tags: gradle, junit5

I would like to enable by default junit extension autoDetection on my project
if i understantd I should use -Djunit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true when i launch my build.

But i want to enable by default without extra parameters in the command line and in all my subModule.

I thing something like that should be good :

```
allprojects {
    test {
        //put an option here
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

}
```

But i've no clue of which option to put in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gradle you can use the system properties extension:

```
test {
    // ...
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled", true)
}
```

See [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-config-params) for further details.